# Conversion of # of people per hour to minutes

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

The question is in the title, I am having some trouble trying to convert:

11 people per hour to # of people entering in minutes

Thanks!

((the question is Poisson based... if that helps))

EDIT: The number of people arriving per hour at the emergency room (ER) of a local hospital seeking medical attention can be modeled by the Poisson distribution, with a mean of 11 people per hour.

How much time in minutes would you expect to pass between the arrival of successive patients seeking medical attention at this ER, in any given hour?

Answer (score 1):

Dimensional analysis:

$$
  \frac{x \text{ things}}{1 \text{ hour}} \times \frac{1 \text{ hour}}{60 \text{ minutes}} = \frac{x \text{ things}}{60 \text{ minutes}} = \frac{(x/60) \text{ things}}{1 \text{ minute}}
$$

So $11$ people in $1$ hour is $11/60 \ (\approx 0.1833)$ people in one minute.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! I should have included the question from my assignment to clarify my question